# Java keep trailing 0 in float operations

Tags: java, zero

the code:

```
Float f = Float.parseFloat("1.80");
System.out.println(f);
```

prints `"1.8"` on screen.
I need to keep the 0 in the float value (Float f) for some validation. How do I do this?

Comment: Do not want to format the string with Df.format... I want to keep the value with 0 in float.

Comment: But... It means the same thing.... Why do you want to do this?

Comment: 1.8 and 1.80 are the same value.  The only difference is how you _display_ it, which is what `format()` is for.  Are you trying to _compare_ the number to something?  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing a *number value* and its *formatting*.  It is **not possible** to actually store `1.80` as a float, however it is possible to *display* the number as a formatted `String` which forces two decimal places.  Your options are:

1. Keep the original String that the user entered, if the number of decimal places they gave
   matters
2. Store the number as a `float`, but when displaying the number force it to display with two decimal places like this:

   `System.out.printf("%.2f\n", f);`

Comment: got it. This case will store as string. Tanks :)

Answer (score 4):

That's simply a formatting issue:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", f);
```

Comment: but how to assign this value in float variable?

Comment: @user2163293: that doesn't make sense.  1.8 and 1.80 are the same value.  If you are interested in validating the sequence of characters "1.80", then you are talking about a string.  In which case, you should store it as a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Floating point variables don't have decimal places. They have binary places.
2. 1.8 and 1.80 are the same number, and they are represented the same way in a `float` or `double`.
3. If you want them *presented* with a certain number of decimal places, you have to convert to a decimal radix, via either `BigDecimal` or `DecimalFormat`, where you can control the number of decimal places.

In short the question doesn't really make sense as posed.